# Gulping the Minimum Hardware Details -- I don't understand how the verb "gulp" is used here

Tags: meaning-in-context, comprehension

Source: [TCP/IP For Dummies, 6th Edition by Candace Leiden and Marshall Wilensky (2009)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixqD0.png)

I don't understand how the verb *gulp* is used here. To gulp, as far as I know, basically means to consume or eat something very quickly, but that doesn't seem to fit the example in the book.

[image]

Comment: *gulp* also has a connotation of skipping the details, same as when you gulp down food you don't really taste it.

Comment: Y'know, not everything someone writes in English will make sense, even to other English speakers.  :)

Comment: For what it's worth, as (1) a native speaker and (2) a professional network engineer, the use of *gulp* in this context makes no sense to me.

Comment: As the title says, the book is for dummies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess that *gulp* is being used in a figurative sense, much like [*digest*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/digest) in *digesting the news*. Here, *gulp* would mean to learn about it quickly, possibly in an easy manner.

> [gulp](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gulp)
>   :  to take in readily as if by swallowing <*gulp down knowledge*>

If learning about hardware has a reputation for being difficult or boring, then using that title might suggest that the material will be covered in a quick or easy manner. It could also suggest *reluctance* by doing it quickly, getting over it, as one might *gulp* some medicine.